# Operator that return a constant reference

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me how can I override an operator () that returns a constant reference to an element of a 2D array at the zero-based position (column x, row y)?
I stored the array data in a T* buffer.
I think that my method declaration should look like this :

```
const T & operator () (int x, int y) const {}
```

Comment: `return buffer[x * row_len + y];`, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`return T[x + y * columns]` is the normal way, where `columns` is the number of columns in the "matrix". `return T[x * rows + y]` is an alternative, where `rows` is the number of rows in the "matrix". Pick either scheme, depending on whether you want the matrix to be trivially resizeable by increasing the number of rows, or by increasing the number of columns.

I've only ever seen this function created with the row parameter passed first. Is your way idiosyncratic?

If you want to be able to *set* elements of the matrix through a reference, then provide the overload

`T & operator () (int x, int y) {/*same function body*/}`

too. Finally, consider using a `size_t` as the parameter, or an `unsigned` type `typedef`fed in your class.

Comment: Thanks for your help